# Where in 5e does it state that the Plane Shift spell's target plane has to be the plane that its tuning fork is attuned to?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

Judging from previous editions, the Plane Shift spell's target plane and the plane its material components are attuned to both have to be the same plane. But, does it actually say that anywhere in this edition? I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### While the PHB spell uses pretty loose language, it is specified in the DMG

The PHB specifies the components required for the [*Plane Shift*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift) (page 266) spell, but the language it uses doesn't provide the constraints we need (***emphasis mine***):

> Components: V, S, M (a forked, metal rod worth at least 250 gp, ***attuned to a particular plane of existence***)

(*PHB > Spells > Plane Shift*)

"A particular plane of existence", however is very loose language which allows the possibility of only needing a tuning fork attuned to the material plane to travel anywhere. Obviously not what we need.

Thankfully, the rules are actually *very* specific, but to find them we need to use an entirely different source book, the Dungeon Master's Guide.

The [DMG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#PlanarTravel) (page 46) has a specific paragraph on the Plane Shift spell as it relates to planar travel (***empasis mine***):

> Plane Shift. The plane shift spell has two important limitations. ***The first is the material component: a small, forked, metal rod (like a tuning fork) attuned to the desired planar destination***. The spell requires the proper resonating frequency to home in on the correct location, and the fork must be made of the right material (sometimes a complex alloy) to focus the spell’s magic properly. [...]

(*DMG > Creating a Multiverse > Planar Travel > Spells > Plane Shift*)